# Action bar menu shows off screen

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have application with old - style menu. After changing theme to Holo and switching target SDK version to 14, soft menu button disappeared (it's OK) but using menu button on action bar shows text menu mostly off-screen as you can see at enclosed image.
Have you any ideas how to fix that?

[image: Action bar error]

I have solved this. Problem was in manifest parameter:

```
   <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="false"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" />
```

After change anyDenisity to true this problem has gone.

Comment: That is very strange. I have never seen that before. If you can create a sample project that reproduces this problem, post it somewhere, as I would like to take a look at it.

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not do the trick for me, the menu still falls mostly off the screen. Any other solutions out there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had similar problem and fixed it by setting `android:anyDensity="true"`. It also fixed other issues like tooltip size on high density screens. According to [android developer guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html#any): **you should not set it "false"**.

Comment: thanks if not preset yet, just add the whole support-screens statement to your manifest! thx, solved my problem!