# Android Action bar overflow menu not show correctly

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, android-menu

[image]

My overflow menu show "cale" instead of "calendar" as following image:

I have add the menu as following:

```
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item android:id="@+id/action_calendar"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_go_to_today"
      app:showAsAction="never"
      android:title="@string/calendar"
      android:showAsAction="never" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_help"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_help"
    android:title="Help"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
    android:title="Check for Updates"/>
   </menu>
```

The activity

```
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

Could anyone tell us what is wrong with my code ?

I think the top left point of the overflow menu rect was incorrect. I have try some example on action bar. It all show the correct as following:

[image]

Hi sorry I have found the problem is caused by setting android:anyDensity="false" on manifest.

[Action bar menu shows off screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257565/action-bar-menu-shows-off-screen)

Thank you!

Comment: try to remove `app:showAsAction="never"` from all your menu item

Comment: Why do you have 2 of the same ID's (action_calendar)?

Comment: remove app:showAsAction="never" but not work.

Comment: This is a very interesting question. Perhaps it may have to do with some confusion in left-to-right text direction, as it seems that the overflow thinks it's left aligned. Are you changing LTR/RTL anywhere in your application [through these mechanisms](http://android-developers.blogspot.nl/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html)?

Comment: I see you've edited your question with a resolution. Please provide that as an answer, so others can learn from your mistake.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Action bar menu shows off screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257565/action-bar-menu-shows-off-screen)